# Как правильно писать?

Tags: глаголы

Возвелича или возвеличив?

Answer (score 1):

Для образования деепричастий совершенного вида, кроме основного суффикса В,  может использоваться основа простого будущего времени и суффикс А/Я: прочтут – прочтя, найдут – найдя.  Обычно это вариантные формы (заметив - заметя) или устойчивые выражения (сломя голову), реже такие деепричастия являются основными: выйдя,  обретя.

Соответственно, для глагола "возвеличить" основным следует считать деепричастие "возвеличив".

Можно предположить, что форма "возвелича" возможна  как разговорная или устаревшая, но это должно быть отмечено в словарях, в текстах же  эти деепричастия встречаются редко.

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае приемлема форма "возвеличив"